# Placesholders in properties file doesn't substitute for environment variables

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app with an application.properties file which has placeholders:

```
tommy.messagebroker.provider=activemq
tommy.messagebroker.tcpaddress=${JMS_HOST}
tommy.messagebroker.port=${JMS_PORT}
```

When I set these environment variables and run the application, **it doesn't substitute** these placeholders for the actual values of the env variables...

this is my main application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.tommy.server"})
public class tommyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuditManagerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

in my pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version> 
 </dependency>
```

anyone knows how to make this substituition happen?

Comment: How do you set these environment variables?

Comment: adding them in Intellij "edit configurations" menu before running the application...

Comment: Share a screenshot of edit configuration plz

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting these environment variables in your local system, and you are using eclipse IDE. Please close out Eclipse and reopen it including your project. for some reason eclipse does not pick up environment variables unless you close the ide and reopen it.